# adjoint matrix using determinant linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A=(a_{ij})$ is an $n$ by $n$ matrix. Define the adjoint of $A$ to be the $n$ by $n$ matrix $adj(A)$ defined by $adj(A)=b_{ij}$, where $b_{ij}=(-1)^{i+j}Det(A_{ji})$. Show that $Aadj(A)=adj(A)A=Det(A)I_n$!

I know how to show the diagonal to be the $Det(A)$ . But I dont know how to show the non diagonal entry to be all zero.

Please help

Comment: Do you know about Cramer's rule?

Comment: how do you apply cramers rule for this tho?

Comment: You could use Cramer's rule to find the entries of the inverse, in the case where $\det(A) \neq 0$.   In particular, the $i,j$ entry of $A^{-1}$ is the $j$th entry of the solution $\mathbf x$ to $A\mathbf x = I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.  To be sure, though, the approach in my answer is quicker.

Answer (score 1):

For example, we consider the first column.  Note that by recognizing a Laplace expansion, we have
$$
[A\operatorname{adj}(A)]_{i1} = 
\sum_{k=1}^n a_{1k}b_{k1} = 
\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^ka_{ik}\det(A_{1k}) = \\
\det \pmatrix{
a_{i1} & a_{i2} & a_{i3} & \cdots\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & \cdots\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & \cdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
}
$$
In all situations with $i \neq 1$, we're taking the determinant of a matrix with a repeated row, which yields a determinant of $0$.

Comment: can you please explain where the repeated row is from?

Comment: Calculate this determinant with a Laplace expansion along the first row, and you'll end up with the sum above